# Matlab UnitTest Coverage

Tags: matlab, unit-testing, code-coverage

Matlab has a fancy new unit-testing framework in 2013a. I've found it quite helpful, but as my modules grow I would like to know how much coverage I have achieved. How can I measure my unit-test coverage, similar to how coverity et al would?

Comment: the IDE has a coverage tool included (been there for quite some time now). Its the profiler itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps my comment was not clear enough. As an example, lets create simple function:

#### folder/test1.m

```
x = zeros(100,1);
for i=1:100
    if rand < 0.8
        x(i) = 1;
    else
        x(i) = 2;
    end
end
```

Now run and profile the script:

```
>> profile on
>> test1
>> profile off
```

Next from the "Current Folder" widget, select "Reports > Coverage Report":

[image: coverage_report]

This will give you a coverage report for all functions/scripts in the current folder:

[image: report]

Clicking on the links will open the regular profile viewer:

[image: prof_viewer]

Obviously you could have directly selected the above options from the profile viewer for each file...

Answer (score 10):

Release 2014b provides a [plugin](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.plugins.codecoverageplugin-class.html) to produce a code coverage report. For example:

```
import matlab.unittest.TestRunner;
import matlab.unittest.TestSuite;
import matlab.unittest.plugins.CodeCoveragePlugin;

% Create a TestSuite array
suite = TestSuite.fromFolder(testFolder);

% Create a runner and add the code coverage plugin
runner = TestRunner.withTextOutput;
runner.addPlugin(CodeCoveragePlugin.forFolder(sourceFolder));

% Run the suite. This opens a code coverage report when done testing.
result = runner.run(suite)
```

Note that the the coverage report should be run on your source code while the test suite is generated from a separate folder. If you use `pwd` as in the linked example, you'll get a coverage report of the tests that you just ran.